# Website Images That Are Cached In Chrome Disappear On Page Refresh

Tags: caching, google-chrome

I'm having a strange issue with Chrome.

I'm working on development with a very image heavy website. If I reload a page over and over again, eventually half the images or more will just disappear. (they don't seem to be broken, just not visible).

If I clear my local cache in Chrome and refresh the page, the images return.

Any idea what may be causing this and how to possibly fix?

edit: just to note, it's not just me. Others hav reported the same issue on the website I'm working on. Always Chrome.

Comment: Try removing the `<ninja>` tag.  Oh wait, that tag is invisible...

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue here in the last few days.  I'm on Chrome 9.0.597.102 beta.  What version are you running?  And are you doing any javascript trickery / manipulation with the photos?  For me, even a test page with just the problem image fails.  Also, are you testing on a local server?

Comment: More info: Looks like others experienced this around 2yrs ago, 1yr ago, and now.  A recurring issue?  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2376e575048e87e0&hl=en .  It mentions extensions; the only extensions I'm running are Evernote and XML Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images, which contains `"content-length"` header randomly disapper, removing this at the server side solves this bug...

(chrome dev team has this issue in `"open"` state in their bug tracing system)

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this recently too. I generally use the latest dev channel for Chrome and assumed it was related to that, but even when launching the regular version of Chrome I get the same issue. I've only noticed it for the past 2-3 months though. Hard-refresh does the job, but it's a really odd bug.